# What is the "Flying Y Ranch"?

Tags: word-meaning, proper-nouns

What is the "Flying Y Ranch" in the following paragraph?

> One day in California, I drove to the end of the box canyon I lived in, took a wooden footbridge over a stream, and climbed through a stand of second-growth redwoods and up a slope lined with blackberry bushes onto Mount Tamalpais, my sacred mountain. Up the steep railroad-tie steps to Cowboy Rock I sweated and panted, my buttocks and lungs burning, up past the county water tank and the dozen rich houses built where the **Flying Y Ranch** used to be.

This is in [this book](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=tSYPVAqJ548C&pg=PA113&lpg=PA113&dq=%22and%20the%20dozen%20rich%20houses%20built%20where%20the%20Flying%20Y%20Ranch%20used%20to%20be.%22&source=bl&ots=wHpnCYSFkX&sig=JBcMUxE9RbMsWu5rY9J1rLk7JEg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLw_Oz9JPKAhUBjZQKHeb8B70Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22and%20the%20dozen%20rich%20houses%20built%20where%20the%20Flying%20Y%20Ranch%20used%20to%20be.%22&f=false).

Comment: It's the name of a ranch, a proper noun.

Comment: "Flying Y" refers to a cattle rancher's brand (each rancher would brand their cattle with a distinctive mark). The "Flying Y Ranch" is the ranch that uses the "flying Y" mark:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livestock_branding#Symbols_and_terminology

Comment: @WimLewis - That's really more of an answer than a comment. I'd suggest you upgrade it to a full-fledged answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reference relates primarily to the path of the Dipsea Race (foot-race) held each year in Marin County, California, just north of San Francisco.

From: http://tinyurl.com/Flying-Y-Ranch

"This week's [article] focuses on just one of the areas of the Dispea race course that was privately owned for many years. It was and still is known to runners as the Flying Y Ranch. The ranch is located on what is now called Walsh Drive. It is just one-quarter of a mile past the top of the final flight of stairs. Currently runners run up Walsh Drive, which is paved. At the top, they enter a dirt trail that has a small resemblance to the dirt path that was there for the better part of 75 years."

"From the first Dipsea Race in 1905 to the late 1970s, runners would pass through the middle of Flying Y Ranch. As far as anyone remembers, there was never an issue of the race being run through any of the privately owned lands. Land owners never really thought of much reason to object. Contrast that today with the constant battles the race committee has with the government jurisdictions that own the public lands, that require permits… it’s a constant headache dealing with those bureaucracies and their agendas."

Answer (score 0):

In the American West (including California), ranches were set up in the 19th century covering large areas of land with cattle herds, as well as the horses needed by the cowboys to manage and drive them. Each ranch used a *brand*, a design for marking the animals it owned, because fences were impractical and ranches did not focus on owning specific areas of land. (The brands were applied by heating iron shapes in a fire and using that to make a scar in the proper shape.) These designs, since they identified all the assets of a large operation, were quite important, and each was identified by a name, usually drawn from the arrangement of shapes in some way, and using a somewhat standardized vocabulary so the brand could be described verbally. For example, the Rocking R would have been the letter R with an arc drawn connecting its legs and curving up a bit beyond on either side, like a rocking chair. So the *Flying Y* brand is a letter Y with strokes added at the top on either side to make wings. And the Flying Y *Ranch* is the ranch that uses that brand.

(Yes, this is where the modern English idea of company "branding" comes from. As important as the Microsoft or Ford brand name is, the original brands were arguably more so.)